# NT AUTHORITY\Local Service is not listed in the Access Control List of a directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, acl

I'm having this issue where I'm trying to check if NT\Authority Local Service has read\execute permissions on a directory (folder). The product that I work on REQUIRES that the folder the user is installing to has read\execute permissions set for Local Service.

The problem is that when I get the Access Control List (ACL) recursively (groups-within-groups), Local Service is not listed so I can't check if he has permissions to that folder or not.

By default, Local Service does not have read/execute permissions to user profiles (My Documents, Desktop, etc...) but I won't know if Local Service has access to other directories the user chooses to install to.

NOTE: Local Service DOES have access to Program Files, even though it is NOT listed in the ACL. Is it hidden somewhere else?

This is a short snippet on how I'm pulling the ACL:

```
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = 
GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityReferenceValue);

// GetMembers(true) is recursive (groups-within-groups)
foreach (var member in groupPrincipal.GetMembers(true)) {
     if (member.SamAccountName.Equals("LOCAL SERVICE")) {
          foundLocalService = true;
           break;
     }
}
```

Is there any other way I should be doing this? (Other than adding an access rule for Local Service on that directory)
Is Local Service just not listed in Directories ACL's?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's notoriously difficult to calculate "effective permissions" for an account. But the simple answer to your question is that you will likely want to look for either on of:

1. The local *Users* group, sometimes shown as *BUILTIN\Users* or *COMPUTERNAME\Users*, or
2. *Authenticated Users*, sometimes shown as *NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users*.

*Authenticated Users* is one of the [well-know SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab). It is "a group that includes all users whose identities were authenticated when they logged on.". As long as you can prove who you are, you are included in *Authenticated Users*. The SID for this is always `S-1-5-11` on every Windows computer.

However, it's not really considered a real group. To find it when adding permissions to a folder, you have to have "Built-in security principals" selected under "Select this object type":

[image: Select Users or Groups]

The local *Users* group contains *Authenticated Users* by default. On my computer, I actually see both *Users* and *Authenticated Users* in the default permissions on the file system.

That's what you will most likely see, and that's likely all that matters.

But that's not the only way. You could see *Everyone* (`S-1-1-0`), which includes every user, authenticated or not.

Or, it could be a file or folder that has the *LOCAL SERVICE* account as the owner.

Or, there could be a local group that was created manually and *LOCAL SERVICE* was added to.

One way to get a more authoritative list of what you can look for is to run this under the *LOCAL SERVICE* account:

```
whoami /groups
```

That will tell you every group in the authentication token, which is every group that you are considered a member of for authentication purposes.

But you can't just open a command prompt as *LOCAL SERVICE*. So one way to do this is to open the Task Scheduler and create a task that runs under *LOCAL SERVICE*, with the action of:

- Program: cmd
- Arguments: /c "whoami /groups > C:\temp\localservice.txt"

Then run the task and, when it's done, look at C:\temp\localservice.txt. It will have a table of group names and their SIDs that you can look for.

Comment: I ran whoami \groups under the running Local Service account and pulled down a lot of groups including Authenticated Users. I discovered that GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity() is not detecting NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users as a group, which would explain the problem because my method only tries to recursively iterate through groups. Wonder why it thinks Authenticated Users is a user and not a group?

Comment: It's not a user or a group. It's a "well-known SID", which has a special meaning to Windows. When adding permissions to a folder, for example, you have to have "Built-in security principals" selected under "Select this object type" (it won't show up if you only have Users or Groups selected). I added a screenshot of that to my answer.